# How to access personal bundle update site from eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse, update-site, eclipse-marketplace

When I try to access my personal update site in the "Install new software" dialog in Eclipse 3.7 I get the following error and therefore cannot download/install any plugins from that update site:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionEcception

Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/user/16293/p2/repo.
Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/user/16293/p2/repo.
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/user/16293/p2/repo is not a valid repository location.
```

This does not seem to be a temporary issue. I get this message since the last 2 months or so.
I don't know what changed, because before that time it worked quite well.

Here's the stacktrace from the .log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 4 0 2012-05-04 15:05:49.778
!MESSAGE Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/user/16293/p2/repo.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to read repository at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/user/16293/p2/repo.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.ProvisioningUI.loadMetadataRepository(ProvisioningUI.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.MetadataRepositoryElement.getMetadataRepository(MetadataRepositoryElement.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.MetadataRepositoryElement.fetchChildren(MetadataRepositoryElement.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.RemoteQueriedElement.fetchDeferredChildren(RemoteQueriedElement.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/user/16293/p2/repo is not a valid repository location.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:102)
    ... 11 more
```

What is going wrong? How can I use my marketplace update site again?

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. Please file a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Community and select as Component "Marketplace".

Comment: Thanks, Tom Seidel.
I filed a bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378497